# SQL RAISE EXCEPTION not working

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm not very good with SQL and I have a small problem with my code.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancelBooking() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $cancelBooking$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.bookingid not in(SELECT bookingid FROM flightbooking)) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'ID NOT FOUND';
    END IF;
END;
$cancelBooking$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER cancelBooking BEFORE UPDATE ON flightbooking
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cancelBooking();




UPDATE flightbooking
SET status = 'C'
WHERE bookingid=11;
```

After I update flightbooking with non existing ID it still says UPDATE 0 which didn't do anything of course but I want it to be an error not successfull query.
Any ideas? I tried to look for a solution on the internet but it didn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that trigger? This looks suspiciously like something that should be a foreign key constraint. And comparing the booking_id from the modified row with **all** rows from the table that is being updated doesn't really make sense to me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the stated question is why it is not working (which is due to the problem discussed in the other answers.  Obviously this will never work since the only case of the trigger being fired never can have be in a snapshot where a row with the same bookingid as NEW will be visible in the same snapshot.

Also I am not 100% sure but I am worried about performance in your function.  (PLPGSQL is a bit funny at times).

Try this instead as it is clearer what is going on under the hood and therefore makes clearer what can be optimized.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancelBooking() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$cancelBooking$
BEGIN
    PERFORM * FROM flightbooking WHERE bookingid = NEW.bookingid;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ID NOT FOUND';
    END IF;
END;
$cancelBooking$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am guessing in most cases that that the performance difference will be very minimal but the performance implications and caveats are clearer so the opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot are less.

**On to a real solution rather than a critique and diagnosis**

This will never work as you have done it. You could do as follows instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancelBooling(_bookingid int) returns void
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM flightbooking WHERE bookingid = _bookingid;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'NOT FOUND';
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: @Matt's problem is that he doesn't get an error if the update to `flightbooking` modifies no row. But in that case the trigger isn't run, and your trigger function won't throw an error.

Comment: Still doesn't raise the error. I have no clue what's wrong with it.

Comment: See my edit for a full solution.  If you want the exception, do the delete trhough the function and check FOUND instead.

Comment: Note, further, as much as I am a fan of stored procedures and udf's, it is probably better to let the containing layer decide how to handle a NOT FOUND rather than raising an exception.  Maybe better to return number of rows deleted?  Or just expect that the client app checks?

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger fires for each row being updated. Because there are no rows to update (the WHERE clause in the UPDATE doesn't find any), the trigger is never fired.

Comment: Still don't understand. How do I fix it? I'm completely new to this.